# How to use same servlet for RPC and upload File in GWT.

Tags: gwt, servlets, gwt-rpc, gwt2, formpanel

i created a web application where i have to use fileUpload.

i have to send the file and their properties to server . For sending a file i used FormPanel and for properties i used RPC .

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final FileServiceEndPoint serviceEndPoint = new FileServiceEndPoint();
    new AddDocument();
    Button b = new Button("addDocument");
    b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        private Map<String, String> docProperty;
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            docProperty =getProperties();
            AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String>() {
                public void onSuccess(String result) {
                    System.out.println("he ha" +result);
                }
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                }
            };
            serviceEndPoint.uploadAttachement(docProperty, callback);
        }
    });
    RootPanel.get().add(b);
}
```

this new AddDocument(); contains code for uploading a file (formPanel code)

```
private FormPanel getFormPanel() {
        if (uploadForm == null) {
            uploadForm = new FormPanel();
            uploadForm.setAction(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() +"TestUploadFileServlet");
            uploadForm.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
            uploadForm.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
            uploadForm.setWidget(getFileUpload());

            System.out.println(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() +"TestUploadFileServlet");

            uploadForm.addFormHandler(new FormHandler() {

                public void onSubmitComplete(FormSubmitCompleteEvent event) {
                    AddDocument.this.hide(true);        
                }

                public void onSubmit(FormSubmitEvent event) {
                }
            });


        }
        return uploadForm;
    }

private Button getAddButton() {
        if (addButton == null) {
            addButton = new Button("ADD");
            addButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    uploadForm.submit();
                }
            });
            addButton.setText("Add");

        }
```

Interface is created for Sending property.

***EndPoints:***

```
public class FileServiceEndPoint implements FileServiceAsync{

FileServiceAsync service = (FileServiceAsync)GWT.create(FileService.class);
ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) service;

public FileServiceEndPoint() {
endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + “TestUploadFileServlet”);
}

public void uploadAttachement(Map docProperty,
AsyncCallback callback) {
service.uploadAttachement(docProperty, callback);
}
}
```

**On Server:**

```
public class FileUploadImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements FileService {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FileUploadImpl.class
.getName());

String a;
protected void service(final HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException,IOException {

a=”5″;
System.out.println(“ServletWorking Fine “);
}
public String uploadAttachement(Map docProperty) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return “Checked”;
}
}
```

**When I debug formPanel.submit : the debugger goes in Server and print ServletWorking Fine(*this is perfect*)**

**and when i debug the addProperties button it goes to server and print ServletWorking Fine. but It should not go in service method.
the debugger should go in UploadAttachement.**

Plz tell how to pass hashMap using same servlet.

Comment: Silly question but: why use the same servlet?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer : because i want to send the Properties of document which is in Hashmap to the server. With the formPanel i will send the file and retrive the Content and mimeType. and with the RPC i will get the property so that i can **combine property, content, mimeType ** and send it to external repository.

Comment: But you'll do two separate requests anyway, so using a single servlet vs. 2 distinct servlets doesn't change much things. In any case, you'll have to store the data/file on the server waiting for the second request to complete the info, so you can combine both and send them to the external repo. (it'd probably be simpler to send everything in the FormPanel though, in a single request)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer :Using FormPanel only widgets can be Send to the server.How to send hashMap through FormPanel.???

Comment: Serialize it (to JSON or whatever) and use a `Hidden` widget; or use one `Hidden` widget per key-value pair (it's a `Map<String,String>` so it's easy)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer : i cant use Hidden cause there are more then 200 properties. and these property depends on document class Selected. Every document class has different property.and also Map<Sting,XYZClass>
this XYZ class has value ,datatype and other property related to the property (key). So adding widgets to form is a bad Idea.
Plzzz Explain how JSON is usefull.